# Matrix generation with octave in a loop

Tags: octave

Hi I want to generate some random matrices of size Nx3 for varying N,  in GNU-Octave. I want to save each of these matrices to a different file.

The script below almost does the job, but strangely it produces only file with the name `int2str(N)` ; it keeps overwriting the files produced at the previous iteration.

```
for i=1:10
  N=(2**i)
  A=rand(N,3);
  save int2str(N) A
end
```

The script is interpreting int2str(N) itself as a string. How do I avoid this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can invoke `save` with the function form:

`save(int2str(N), "A")`